# How to solve matrix equation $AX + B = XC$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How to solve matrix equation $AX + B = XC$, where $X$ is the unknown matrix $3 \times 3$?
I can't find any way of getting $X$ out of there. Both $X's$ are on opposite sides. There are no two matrices which are the same so you can't factor anything out.

The matrices are by the way:
$A =\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix},$
$B =\begin{bmatrix}-8&4&-8\\8&-4&8\\-8&4&-8\end{bmatrix},$
$C =\begin{bmatrix}2&2&1\\1&3&2\\0&1&2\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: X is a 3x3 matrix as well otherwise, if X is a single column vector then XC doesn't make sense.

Comment: take a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation

Comment: We have 9 linear equations with 9 unknowns. It an be rewritten as $Mx=b\implies x = M^{-1}b$.

Comment: @MatheusNunes Nunes Isn't there a different way? We didn't learn this.

Comment: @Klaas van Aarsen Yeah, I can transform that into a $9 \times 9$ but we had like an hour for the entire test and this was one of three questions, so there has to be a better way.

Comment: The solution is by the way
$\:4\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1 & 1 & -1\\1&-1&1\\-1 & 1 & -1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.
It is unique, and was obtained with Python's [LinAlg package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_sylvester.html) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My post will probably not help the OP. My idea is to show what the tensor product is for.

We put $Y=1/4X$; then the equation is

$AY-YC=-1/4B$, that is, $(*)$ $(A\otimes I-I\otimes C^T)Y=-1/4B$, if we stack the matrices, row by row, into vectors; cf.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

$spectrum(A)=\{-1,0,2\}$ and $\chi_C=x^3-7x^2+12x-5$; then

$(\lambda_i)=spectrum(A)\cap (\mu_i)=spectrum(C)=\emptyset$.

Since $spectrum(A\otimes I-I\otimes C^T)=\{\lambda_i-\mu_j;i,j\}$, $(*)$ admits a unique solution.

Note that i) $Av=-v$ where $v=[1,-1,1]^T$.

ii)$-1/4B=v\otimes [2,-1,2]^T=v\otimes (v+u)^T$, where $u=[1,0,1]^T$.

iii) $Cv=u$.

We seek the solution in decomposable form: $Y=k\otimes l^T$. $(*)$ becomes $Ak\otimes l^T-k\otimes (Cl)^T=v\otimes (v+u)^T$.

That works for $k=-v, l=v$; then $Y=-v\otimes v^T=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&-1\\1&-1&1\\-1&1&-1\end{pmatrix}$, that is, the Hanno's result.

-Time of thinking (1 hour); I would have done a third of the test-

Comment: Well that's depressing. Seems like there is no other way than brute force since we haven't done tensor products. Tightly timed exams are hell.